# My DLL doesn't work properly when it's placed on System's directory

Tags: .net, windows, dll, com, c++-cli

I wrote a COM DLL that is loaded from a third party application (which uses VBA for scripting).

At startup, a value is passed to the DLL by the application in order to find its instance afterwards.

This (unmanaged) value is a specific type to the application that I made `static` and global (it's outside any classes).

The DLL is correctly registered in registry (with `regasm`) and the third party application loads correctly the DLL.

The DLL is placed onto System's directory (i.e. System32 or SysWoW64).

In Windows XP, the DLL works like a charm, but in Windows 7 (64 bits), there is an issue : **the static value becomes null** ! However, the rest of the DLL works good, just this value is buggy.

On the other side, when we place the DLL in a non-system's folder, it's OK.

I think that the GC destroy the value, but it's impossible because there is static and unmanaged.

The problem it is with GC ? Why the system's folder doesn't work (even with admin rights) ? Is there a speciality with Windows7 ?

Comment: No, the garbage collector doesn't give a hoot where you put your DLL.  You are still a long way from using a debugger to diagnose your problem, a data breakpoint will do wonders.  There's little point at guessing at the reason until you get this done.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the fact that the DLL is loaded by the third-party application makes it impossible to debug. In place, I have put some `MessageBox` in the code.

Comment: The `MessageBox` show me that the static value is correctly initialized then it directly becomes `nullptr`.

Comment: Of course you can debug a DLL in such a scenario, just select the client EXE as the Command setting in the Debugging settings.  If you've never once did this yet then it is almost guaranteed that you have a bug.  You didn't debug it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is clear now : the bug is on third party application and not my code. Some strange stuffs happened when we put the DLL into System's folder.

Comment: The system folder is for system libraries not application libraries--yes, even on Windows.

Comment: They are some mechanisms to prevent or limit access from this folder for application libraries?

Comment: Nope. Once an administrator gives permission for your installer to run, you can do anything you choose to. It's just a best practice (sorry can't find a link to MS guidance) to design applications to they can be installed elsewhere, e.g. common application files in [CommonFilesFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_folder_properties). The solution needs to begin with the developers of the program; some problems can't be solved in the installer.

Comment: The fact is even with full admin rights, the third party application will have strange issues when it loads the DLL from the system's folder.